# ListView with Image background

Tags: listview, javafx, scenebuilder

I have an ListView inside this window, and I set sky image as an effect(in SceneBuilder).
But now I cant see my list. Is it possible to have image background and also list to choose from?

[image]

Controller class:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
@FXML
ListView<String> listView;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ObservableList<String> list;
    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Opcja 1", "Opcja 2");
    listView.setItems(list);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display a background image behind a `ListView` you have to remove the background color on each of its `ListCell`s. Here is a sample:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    String image = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG";

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableList(IntStream
            .range(1000, 2000).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(data);
    listView.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image(
            image), BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
            BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And the necessary CSS code:

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

Hint: In most cases you will add a custom CSS class (e.g. `.my-cell`) to each of your cells and use that class instead of `.list-cell` because the current code would apply to every `ListCell`.

Comment: it took me a while to make it in my controller class, but I get it eventually ;)  how can I change color of text, background and size in my list?

Comment: Since the `ListCell` is a `Labeled` there are several CSS options to do that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled